Unity TileMap Tiling rules using only the top rule
I am making a game in unity using TileMap and I have a problem.
I made my own Rule Tile script, where I added my own rules - to check if the neighbor tile is from one of 4 arrays - room with top/bottom/left/right entrance, because I want rooms to connect with entrances, so there isn't a lot of dead ends. (I also added a script, which changes the icons in unity explorer). I also added rule to check if the tile is NOT from an array.
But I got into a problem. Tiling rules use only the first and last rule, others are ignored (image). I tried changing the order (still rule on first place is used), but nothing happened.
Rule tile script:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "VinTools/Custom Tiles/Advanced Rule Tile")]
public class AdvancedRuleTile : RuleTile<AdvancedRuleTile.Neighbor>
{
    [Header("Advanced Tile")]
    [Tooltip("If enabled, the tile will connect to these tiles too when the mode is set to \"This\"")]
    public bool alwaysConnect;
    [Tooltip("Tiles to connect to")]
    public TileBase[] tilesToConnect;

    public TileBase[] topEntrance;
    public TileBase[] bottomEntrance;
    public TileBase[] leftEntrance;
    public TileBase[] rightEntrance;

    
    [Space]
    [Tooltip("Check itseft when the mode is set to \"any\"")]
    public bool checkSelf = true;

    public class Neighbor : RuleTile.TilingRule.Neighbor
    {
        public const int Any = 3;
        public const int Nothing = 4;

        public const int topEntrance = 5;
        public const int bottomEntrance = 6;
        public const int leftEntrance = 7;
        public const int rightEntrance = 8;

        
        public const int notTopEntrance = 9;
        public const int notBottomEntrance = 10;
        public const int notLeftEntrance = 11;
        public const int notRightEntrance = 12;
        

    }

    public override bool RuleMatch(int neighbor, TileBase tile)
    {
        switch (neighbor)
        {
            case Neighbor.This: return Check_This(tile);
            case Neighbor.NotThis: return Check_NotThis(tile);
            case Neighbor.Any: return Check_Any(tile);
            case Neighbor.Nothing: return Check_Nothing(tile);

            case Neighbor.topEntrance: return Check_topEntrance(tile);
            case Neighbor.bottomEntrance: return Check_bottomEntrance(tile);
            case Neighbor.leftEntrance: return Check_leftEntrance(tile);
            case Neighbor.rightEntrance: return Check_rightEntrance(tile);

           
            case Neighbor.notTopEntrance: return Check_notTopEntrance(tile);
            case Neighbor.notBottomEntrance: return Check_notBottomEntrance(tile);
            case Neighbor.notLeftEntrance: return Check_notLeftEntrance(tile);
            case Neighbor.notRightEntrance: return Check_notRightEntrance(tile);
           
        }
        return base.RuleMatch(neighbor, tile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the tile is this, or if the tile is one of the tiles specified if always connect is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tile">Neighboring tile to compare to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool Check_This(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (!alwaysConnect) return tile == this;
        else return tilesToConnect.Contains(tile) || tile == this;

        //.Contains requires "using System.Linq;"
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the tile is not this.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tile">Neighboring tile to compare to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool Check_NotThis(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (!alwaysConnect) return tile != this;
        else return !tilesToConnect.Contains(tile) && tile != this;

        //.Contains requires "using System.Linq;"
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return true if the tile is not empty, or not this if the check self option is disabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tile">Neighboring tile to compare to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool Check_Any(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the tile is empty.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tile">Neighboring tile to compare to</param>
    /// <param name="tile"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool Check_Nothing(TileBase tile)
    {
        return tile == null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the tile is one of the specified tiles.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tile">Neighboring tile to compare to</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    
   

    bool Check_topEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile == topEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //return topEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //.Contains requires "using System.Linq;"
    }

    bool Check_bottomEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile == bottomEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //return bottomEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //.Contains requires "using System.Linq;"
    }

    bool Check_leftEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile == leftEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //return leftEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //.Contains requires "using System.Linq;"
    }

    bool Check_rightEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile == rightEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //return rightEntrance.Contains(tile);
        //.Contains requires "using System.Linq;"
    }


    
    bool Check_notTopEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile != topEntrance.Contains(tile);
    }

    bool Check_notBottomEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile != bottomEntrance.Contains(tile);
    }

    bool Check_notLeftEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile != leftEntrance.Contains(tile);
    }

    bool Check_notRightEntrance(TileBase tile)
    {
        if (checkSelf) return tile != null;
        else return tile != null && tile != this && tile != rightEntrance.Contains(tile);
    }
    
} 

Here are screenshots of my tiling rules: 1, 2, 3

black "R" means room with entrance on right, etc. for other letters
red "R" means room with NO entrance or right, etc. for other letters

If you are wondering how the tiles look, it's here: image
Does somebody know why is it happening or how to fix it?
Thank you

What is the purpose of your bool checkSelf? Removing it and just simplifying the checks to be return topEntrance.Contains(tile) and nothing else (different list for each check, obviously) makes it work just fine, but I have no clue what checkSelf is supposed to do so I can't say it's an answer...

I know that it was there, I removed it after because its unused. It not an answer.

Is just doing return topEntrance.Contains(tile) fine?

It doesn't work, I have no idea why. No error, everything set up, but still nothing. Isn't it somehow required to override the old tiles? Nothing seems to work.
